# Passing a variable from Tkinter to main program

Tags: python, tkinter

Maybe this is easy, but I just don't figure it out ...

In the code below the "File Open" Button saves the filename to "name" -- but  how can I access this variable outside of Tkinter? A return statement in "callback", but how would I access that since callback is inside the "Button" command?

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog   import askopenfilename      

def callback():
    name= askopenfilename() 
    print name

Button(text='File Open', command=callback).pack(fill=X)
mainloop()

#HOW DO I ACCESS FILENAME AFTER MAINLOOP?
name = ????
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eh, How about this?

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename      

value_list = []

def callback():
    name = askopenfilename() 
    value_list.append(name)
    print name

Button(text='File Open', command=callback).pack(fill=X)
mainloop()

# value_list[0] is filename
```

Comment: that would be a solution, thanks :-)  --- but is this the standard way of doing this?

Comment: @Max I'm not sure what the standard way is, but I can assure you that you can't return from the callback.

Comment: works fine your solution -- I use a dictionary instead of a list to adress specific values when having more than one, so value_dict = {'inputfilepath': 'G:\\satellittdata\\flerbrukBarents', 'outputfilepath': 'G:\\satellittdata\\flerbrukBarents'} and in the function value_dict['inputfilepath'] =  name

Comment: @Max Sure, dict would be better.